# Important Infos - Senchatouch + Phonegap into AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, cordova, sencha-touch

What are the things to pay attention combinating SenchaTouch (HTML-JAVAscript) with Phonegap to get an App for the AppStore?

Which things are important to get such apps into the appstore without refuse?

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/submission/tips.html

http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

In particular:

12.3 Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a collection of links, may be rejected

Answer (score 0):

Using Sencha Touch with Phonegap hasn't caused ANY problems for the app that i've developed. I got rejected once for not supporting both directions on display orientation (not only was it landscape only, it was only one direction of the landscape. Currently, it's landscape only and it's been approved many times).

It seems like you really ONLY need to worry about the same guidelines that you normally need to worry about. It feels weird having 100 javascript files and only a  couple objective C files, but they dont' put up any fuss, and our wait times for approval were great.